# Error when trying to write spark to mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to append data to mongodb using spark streaming and I face some issue. Here is my code:

```
def write_to_db(df, epoch_id):
    df.select("id", "production_companies").show()
    df.write.format("mongodb") \
               .mode("append") \
               .option("database", "BIGDATA") \
               .option("collection", "movie") \
               .save()
# ----------------------------------------------------------
packages = [
    f'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_{scala_version}:{spark_version}',
    'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.5.0',
    'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:3.0.0',
    'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12:7.17.16',
     "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:10.2.1"
]

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master(MASTER) \
    .appName("Movie Consumer") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", ",".join(packages)) \
    .config(f"spark.mongodb.input.uri", f"mongodb+srv://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@atlascluster.zdoemtz.mongodb.net") \
    .config(f"spark.mongodb.output.uri", f"mongodb+srv://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@atlascluster.zdoemtz.mongodb.net") \
    .config("spark.cores.max", "1") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "1g") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("Error")
```

And I get an error:

```
23/12/22 01:35:19 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.apply(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/encoders/ExpressionEncoder;    
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.schema.InternalRowToRowFunction.<init>(InternalRowToRowFunction.java:44)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.schema.RowToBsonDocumentConverter.<init>(RowToBsonDocumentConverter.java:84)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.write.MongoDataWriter.<init>(MongoDataWriter.java:74)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.write.MongoDataWriterFactory.createWriter(MongoDataWriterFactory.java:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WritingSparkTask.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:436)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WritingSparkTask.run$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:425)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:491)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)   
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)    
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)    
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
23/12/22 01:35:19 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
23/12/22 01:35:19 ERROR AppendDataExec: Data source write support com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.write.MongoBatchWrite@63533b1d is aborting.
23/12/22 01:35:19 ERROR AppendDataExec: Data source write support com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.write.MongoBatchWrite@63533b1d failed to abort.
23/12/22 01:35:19 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 17fcc2cb-65aa-4a50-8d2b-db0b0dc8f3dd, runId = 79f5c5d2-7623-4524-9bcd-e6dabe023804] terminated with error
py4j.Py4JException: An exception was raised by the Python Proxy. Return Message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\py4j\clientserver.py", line 617, in _call_proxy
    return_value = getattr(self.pool[obj_id], method)(*params)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 120, in call
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 117, in call
    self.func(DataFrame(jdf, wrapped_session_jdf), batch_id)
  File "D:\IT4931-bigdata-Movie-processing\app\movie_consumer.py", line 31, in write_to_elasticsearch
    .save()
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 1461, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 179, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o107.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job failed.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.writingJobFailedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:411)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:359)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AppendDataExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:225)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2ExistingTableWriteExec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2ExistingTableWriteExec.run$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:336)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AppendDataExec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:225)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.executeCollect(V2CommandExec.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)     
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:437)     
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:142)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:859)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:312)       
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:248)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)      
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.sendCommand(ClientServerConnection.java:244)
        at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:384)
        at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:356)
        at py4j.reflection.PythonProxyHandler.invoke(PythonProxyHandler.java:106)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.PythonForeachBatchHelper$.$anonfun$callForeachBatch$1(ForeachBatchSink.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.PythonForeachBatchHelper$.$anonfun$callForeachBatch$1$adapted(ForeachBatchSink.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.addBatch(ForeachBatchSink.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$17(MicroBatchExecution.scala:732)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:427)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:425)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:286)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:427)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:425)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:249)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:311)
...
```

I use Scala 2.12 and Spark 3.5.0. I think there may be a mismatched version of mongo-spark-connector. However, I can't find another one that fits my spark. Is there any way that I don't need to downgrade my Spark version? Thank you very much.

Comment: According to their [GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/cece3b52e4fba1862ea79099aaa7e0fcadd254bc/build.gradle.kts#L54) and my understanding, the connector is compiled against Spark 3.2 and thus there may be incompatibilities.

Comment: yeah, this discussion from mongoDB talks about the version too (and doc said it works with spark from 3.1 to 3.2.4)
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/getting-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-when-trying-to-write-to-a-collection-via-spark-mongo-connector/237021